# input type number has different shape in Chrome and Firefox browser

Tags: html, css

I want to add a  with limited character input. Only number and . (dot) as decimal separator. By default  has arrow up and down for increase and decrease number, in this case i want to hide the arrows.

Here my code :

**CSS for hiding the arrows :**

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}
```

**HTML code :**

```
<input id="abc" type="number" class="abc" name="abc" pattern="[0-9]+([\.][0-9]+)?" readonly="readonly" step="0.000000000000000001" title="The number input must start with a number and use dot as a decimal character." value="" />
```

**Main Problem :**

The code above working perfectly in Chrome browser but fail in FireFox.

**In Chrome browser :**

1. I can't type comma, i just only type number and dot. And i want number and dot only.
2. I can hide arrow up and down as i want.

**In firefox** i still can type comma (,). I want use dot (.) only as decimal separator. In firefox too, up and down arrow still appear. Any help?

Comment: `::-webkit-` selects only Chrome. You need to use `::-moz-` for Firefox.

Comment: @praveen-kumar : how if i want to set it as global setting for any browser?

Comment: You need to set for every vendor prefix.